# Comment function for page

Tags: functions, comments, advanced-custom-fields, comments-template

I'm trying to include my comments.php on a page and my custom comment function isn't returning any result (works on posts). 
Please help me sort this.

I want to be able to create a ACF block to include a custom comment block (but can be styled the same as on pages).

Function

```
function zeuligan_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
if ( 'div' === $args['style'] ) {
    $tag       = 'div';
    $add_below = 'comment';
} else {
    $tag       = 'li ';
    $add_below = 'div-comment';
}?>
<<?php echo $tag; comment_class( empty( $args['has_children'] ) ? '' : 'parent' ); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>"><?php 
if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) { ?>
    <div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body"><?php
} ?>
    <div class="comment-author vcard"><?php 
        if ( $args['avatar_size'] != 0 ) {
            echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); 
        }; ?>
    </div><?php 
    if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) { ?>
        <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?></em><br/><?php 
    } ?>
    <div class="comment-content">
    <?php printf( __( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite>' ), get_comment_author_link() ); ?>
    <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
        <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>"><?php
            printf( 
                __('%1$s at %2$s'), 
                get_comment_date(),  
                get_comment_time() 
            ); ?>
        </a><?php 
        edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)' ), '  ', '' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php comment_text(); ?>
    <div class="reply"><?php 
            comment_reply_link( 
                array_merge( 
                    $args, 
                    array( 
                        'add_below' => $add_below, 
                        'depth'     => $depth, 
                        'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ); ?>
    </div>
    </div>

<?php 
    if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
        </div><?php 
    endif;
}
```

the comments.php

```
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) { return; } ?>
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">
    <?php
    if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php
            $comments_number = get_comments_number();
            if ( '1' === $comments_number ) {
                printf( _x( 'One Reply to &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'comments title', 'zeuligan' ), get_the_title() );
            } else {
                printf(
                _nx(
                    '%1$s Reply to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;',
                    '%1$s Replies to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;',
                    $comments_number,
                    'comments title',
                    'zeuligan'
                ),
                number_format_i18n( $comments_number ),
                get_the_title()
            );
        }
        ?>
        </h2>

        <ul class="comment-list">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'avatar_size' => 100,
                    'style'       => 'ul',
                    'callback'    => 'zeuligan_comment',
                    'short_ping'  => true,
                    'reply_text'  => 'Reply',
                ) );
            ?>
        </ul>

            <?php the_comments_pagination( array(
                'prev_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous', 'zeuligan' ) . '</span>',
                'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next', 'zeuligan' ) . '</span>',
            ) );

        endif;

        if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) : ?>
            <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'zeuligan' ); ?></p>
        <?php
        endif;
        comment_form();
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: does the commenting work on a page **without** your custom code? with other words, does your theme allow and show comments on pages?

Comment: It is I who has build the theme from scratch and it's my first time coding, so might be hard to answer :)

I checked the box for comments in admin for the specific page. I can get the form to show, but can't get actual comments to show on the page (but on posts).

Comment: Figured it out, think I complicated matters and called the same template twice. 

Adding the code    <?php
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
     comments_template();
    }
to my ACF block worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this my self. The solution was as simple to just call the comments template. Think I originally messed up by calling the template twice

```
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
            comments_template();
        }
```